# What is the SNMP OID for jvm Thread block count

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, snmp

I need to get the value for jvm thread block count using OID so that a graph can be drawn using cacti. I have searched a lot but found only following OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.10.1.4. When I try snmpwalk it returns sub OID's with Counter64 values. Above OID represents

> The total number of times that this thread has blocked to enter or re-enter a monitor..

When I snmpwalk above, it returns values for each thread and its blocked value. But I want the count of all the threads which got blocked in specified time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply there is no such counter.
All available JVM OIDs are listed [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be698ac28848/src/share/classes/sun/management/snmp/jvmmib/JVM_MANAGEMENT_MIBOidTable.java#l59).

The closest JVM metrics you may be interested in is `sun.rt._sync_ContendedLockAttempts` counter.

Here is how to get it from Java:

```
import sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper;
import sun.management.counter.Counter;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getContendedLockAttempts());
    }

    private static long getContendedLockAttempts() {
        for (Counter counter : ManagementFactoryHelper.getHotspotRuntimeMBean().getInternalRuntimeCounters()) {
            if ("sun.rt._sync_ContendedLockAttempts".equals(counter.getName())) {
                return (long) counter.getValue();
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

Or from the command line:

```
jcmd {PID} PerfCounter.print | grep sun.rt._sync_ContendedLockAttempts
```